# App with Theme.NoDisplay won't fire runtime.exec()

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app, that doesn't have any UI and just sends a KeyEvent on launch, then close itself. I got everything working when I use an activity, and do

```
onCreate(){
//the Toast stuff
runtime.exec("input keyeven " + KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) //with try catch error 
//handling and printing the exception
finish();
}
```

, however, if in the manifest I set

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

the runtime command isn't executed. Other things (like calling Toast messages) work and no error or exceptions are thrown. Is there a fix or another way of creating such a thing?

Expected: Appicon clicked, keyevent fired, rest of code executes
Actual:   Appicon clicked, no keyevent fired, rest of code executes

Comment: Can you guys reproduce? Or is this "bug" only affecting me for some reason?